# SQL: Why is column avg_spent getting an error that it does not exist?

Tags: group-by, having

SELECT
city,
usd_spent / count(city) AS avg_spent
FROM travel_spending
GROUP BY city HAVING avg_spent > 90;

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Certain versions of SQL (e.g. MySQL) allow the use of aliases in the `HAVING` clause, while other versions (e.g. SQL Server) do not.  In any case, just repeating the aggregate expression in the `HAVING` clause should work:

```
SELECT city, AVG(usd_spent) AS avg_spent
FROM travel_spending
GROUP BY city
HAVING AVG(usd_spent) > 90;
```

Comment: Thank you - However I got this error. ERROR: column "travel_spending.usd_spent" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Line: 1 Position in the line: 14

Comment: @user10638261 I think you just want the average USD spend here.